# Multi-line text values in Dyalog APL

Tags: apl, dyalog

How to code a multi-line text value in Dyalog APL?

I want to code something like this:

```
query←'
SELECT *
FROM SOME_TABLE
'
```

to be able to copy this text to SQL Developer and back.

I know that I could code it this way:

```
query←''
query,←'SELECT * '
query,←'FROM SOME_TABLE '
```

But it would not allow me to copy this text to SQL Developer and back easily.

Is it possible to temporary override the newline character in Dyalog APL function source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S←{a←⍺⍺⋄,⎕cr'a'}
query←{
 SELECT *
 FROM Some_Table
}S⍬
```

Comment: Nice trick, thank you. There are some issues with it:

1) the query is being surrounded by 'a←{' and '}' with some spaces
2) '}' characters within query (in string constants) are not supported
3) Dyalog APL formats the query its own way.

The trimming could be done this way:

    query←(query⍳'{')↓(¯1+query⍳'}')↑query

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid Multiline-Strings aren't there (yet, I hope).

The only way around this would be do write it as follows:

```
query←ScriptFollows
⍝ SELECT *
⍝ FROM Some_Table
```

When pasting from SQL Dev, select the inserted text and click the <kbd>**⍝**</kbd> button on the editor toolbar to insert the comment symbol on each line.

If using the IDE, click and hold the right mouse button to select a rectangular block without the comment symbols.

P.S: you need to define the fn ScriptFollows - here is one way to do it (courtesy of Brian Becker):

```
∇ r←ScriptFollows;lines;pgm;from
 ⍝ Treat following commented lines in caller as a script, lines beginning with ⍝⍝ are stripped out
  :If 0∊⍴lines←(from←⎕IO⊃⎕RSI).⎕NR pgm←2⊃⎕SI
      lines←↓from.(180⌶)pgm
  :EndIf
  r←2↓∊CRLF∘,¨{⍵/⍨'⍝'≠⊃¨⍵}{1↓¨⍵/⍨∧\'⍝'=⊃¨⍵}dtlb¨(1+2⊃⎕LC)↓lines
∇
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature was actually available many years ago on (mainframe) systems based on APL\360, such as Sharp APL (removed around 1980?), STSC APL*Plus, and others.  Among other things, it was no longer possible to go back edit such a line with embedded carriage returns with the normal del editor (full screen editors, as such, did not exist yet).  It was removed as it may have been confusing for users - the system expected a closing quote and just pressing return did not implicitly provide one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dusting off an old thread that I found when I ran into this problem.
My solution was this:

```
z←1↓¯1↓(1=+\∨/z=⎕UCS 8711)⌿z←⎕CR⊃⎕SI
 →Label

 ∇
   multi-
   line
   stuff
   goes
   here
 ∇
Label:
```

The first thing that happens is that we get the Character Representation of *first* State Indicator (that's **this function**) into variable `z`

Then find the rows in `z` with ∇ glyphs. `z=⎕UCS 8711` (Note: we can't use the glyph here! That would introduce a third occurrence.)

Sum this Boolean cumulatively `+\`. This makes the enclosed rows into 1s as well. Unfortunately it also makes the lines after the enclosed block into 2s.

Therefore, we check for 1s `1=` and now we're back to Boolean.

Now, use Compress `⌿` to preserve only these rows and finally drop the first and the last rows to leave out the ∇s.

At this point we're done, but we must jump past the un-executable rows in our script.